# why com.ExecuteNonQuery() return -1 Always . in all cases

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection, executenonquery

`com.ExecuteNonQuery()` always returns -1 - in all cases.

Why is it always = -1 ?

```
SqlConnection conn = newSqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

conn.Open();

string insertquery = " select UserName from Users where Username='" + CurrentName + "' ";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertquery, conn);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();

int ii = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

Response.Write(ii);
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` twice? And why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` when it *is* a query? And why have you called it `insertquery` when it's just a select query? There's no insertion there...

Comment: even i calling one time: also return -1 in all cases

Comment: Why is it called `insertquery` when it really contains a `SELECT`?

Comment: You are using `ExecuteNonQuery` but you want to _SELECT_ something (that **IS** a query!) Please use the correct query-function. For example `ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a select Query so the result will always be -1.

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using it with a `SELECT` SQL command.

From the documentation for [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery) (emphasis mine):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.** If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but this basically isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you I did not know that

Comment: @محمودالعطاس: In general, when something doesn't behave as you expect it to, the *first* thing you should do is consult the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
string query = "select UserName from Users where lower(Username)=lower('" + CurrentName + "')";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
string result = "";
result = com.ExecuteScalar() == null ? "" : com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
conn.Close();
Response.Write(result);
```

try out this